NestJS: transform prop marked as 'toPlainOnly' is processed even when transforming to instance
I have an entity that masks the values when sending them to the client:
@Entity('tada')
export class DaEntity extends AbstractCustomerRelationEntity {

  @Column({ type: 'jsonb' })
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @Expose({ toClassOnly: true, groups: [TG_RBT] })
  config: any;

  @Expose({ toPlainOnly: true, name: 'config', groups: [TG_EDIT] })
  @Transform(({ obj }) => {
    const retVal: any = {};
    // process the stored config to remove/mask some values
    return retVal;
  }, { toPlainOnly: true })
  transformedConfig: any;

}

The controller endpoints have these annotations:
  @Get(':id')
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  @SerializeOptions({ groups: [TG_EDIT] })
  getConfig(@AuthUser() user: AuthenticatedUser, @Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.service.getConfig(user, id);
  }


  @Put()
  @UsePipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true, groups: [TG_EDIT],
      transformOptions: { excludeExtraneousValues: true, groups: [TG_EDIT, TG_RBT] },
    }),
  )
  updateConfig(@AuthUser() user: AuthenticatedUser, @Body() body: DaEntity) {
    return this.service.save(user, body);
  }


So when the server sends the entity to client the config is processed and masked. So far so good.
The weird fact is when I send the entity back, in my opinion I should have "vanilla" config there sent from client, however it's not. The @Transform is processed and the incoming object has transformedConfig property (although with verbatim values, not masked).
How come? What is there that I did wrong?
